# Error RecyclerView con imagenes Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Cargo imagenes en un recycler view pero me aparecen espacios en banco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adaptador:

```
   package com.example.recyclerview;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdapterDatos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDatos.ViewHolderDatos> {


    ArrayList<String> listDatos;

    public AdapterDatos(ArrayList<String> listDatos)
    {

        this.listDatos = listDatos;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,null,false);

        return new ViewHolderDatos(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {
       holder.asignarDatos(listDatos.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listDatos.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        ImageView imagen;




        public ViewHolderDatos(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imagen=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagen_dato);
        }

        public void asignarDatos(String s) {

            imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.gato);

        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
    package com.example.recyclerview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> listDatos;
    RecyclerView recycler;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recycler=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.RecyclerId);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
        listDatos= new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            listDatos.add("Dato: " + i);
        }
       AdapterDatos adapter=new AdapterDatos(listDatos);
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Items XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen_dato"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedo notar que tu archivo `item_list.xml` indica que tienes un alto definido como `match_parent` , deberìa ser `wrap_content`, realiza el cambio:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen_dato"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

- [`MATCH_PARENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams) indica que la vista quiere ser tan grande como su padre (menos relleno).
- [`WRAP_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams), indica que la vista quiere ser lo suficientemente grande como para incluir su contenido (más relleno).

---

Dentro de tu Adapter, realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

       //View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,null,false);
         View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolderDatos(view);
    }
```

Comment: Jorgesys ya lo probe como me indicates y igual sigue generando items vacios al parecer.

Comment: En el mètodo onCreateViewHolder() de tu Adapter realiza el cambio que sugiero @Javier

Comment: Jorgesys realice el cambio en el método que me indicaste y sigue lo mismo.

Comment: Los espacios dejaron de aparecer cuando dentro del ImagenView cambie a :        android:layout_height="200dp"

Comment: @Javier prueba también con android:layout_height="wrap_content"